# The fundamental group of the complement of codimension 2 submanifold

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose that $M^n$, $V^{n+2}$ are connected, compact smooth manifolds.

Let $f\colon M^n\to V^{n+2}$ is a smooth embedding.

Let $K_f$ be the kernel of the inclusion induced homomorphism $\pi_1(V-f(M))\to \pi_1(V)$.

Choose a meridian $\mu\in \pi_1(V-f(M))$.

Proposition 1.3 of Smith's paper, *Complements of codimension two sub-manifolds I: The Fundamental group, Illinois J. Math. 1978 p. 232-239* says that if $f_*\colon \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(V)$ is a surjection, then $K_f$ is normally generated by $\mu$.

**Question**: Is the condition that $f_*\colon \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(V)$ is surjective necessary? That is, is there an embedding $f\colon M\to V$ such that $K_f$ is not normally generated by just one meridian?

Comment: This is not a condition, as it always holds. E.g., because any loop in $V$ can be made disjoint from $M$.

Comment: The condition is $f_*\colon \pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(V)$ is surjective not $\operatorname{inc}_*\colon \pi_1(V-f(M))\to \pi_1(V)$ is surjective.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Still, this does not seem necessary. One can probably derive this from Zariski--van Kampen, but an easier way is to take a loop $\gamma$ in $V\setminus M$, assume that it bounds a disk, and then make this disk transverse to $M$. Then it's clear that $\gamma$ is the product of a bunch of loops conjugate to the meridian.

Comment: I guess one has to invoke the tubular neighborhood theorem to see that all meridians are conjugate to each other.